# Recovering file icons

Tags: finder, icon

Recently the icons on a couple of files with particular file extensions have disappeared, particularly .csv and .tex files. The icons used to be there -- how can I get them back?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you've removed an app that was previously used to open the files?

Comment: They're still there, and open up in the default app just fine.